VSCode: Incorrect indentation after method chaining?
After I've concluded a block with method chaining, VSCode keeps the indentation until I format on save.
Example:
$orders = Order::paid()
    ->notShipped()
    ->get();

    dd($orders); // <-- This line should not be indented to match the method chaining

This is how it's supposed to look (and it does when I format on save, but VSCode shouldn't indent in the first place:
$orders = Order::paid()
    ->notShipped()
    ->get();

dd($orders); // <-- Much better :)

It works when I save because I run Laravel Pint when saving.

It seems like a bug in the formatter. Raise an issue on their GitHub page.
